# how to write to new text file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to write every line that i get to a test.txt file. However every result needs to be in its own line. Am i missing something or did i not corectly implemented "\n"? For better understanding my code reads 3th work in a line and if that word matches P***ei "*" meaning any letter from a-z (A-Z) or S**ei and returns first word in that line as an result. The code worked but now when i write to file it doesnt print each word in its own line.

```
package test;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.io.FileWriter;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class moja {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("SloveneLexicon.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String vrstica;
            File test = new File("test.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(test);
            while ((vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                String s = vrstica;
                String[] dobi_besedo_v_vrstici = s.split("\\s+");
                String prva_beseda = dobi_besedo_v_vrstici[0];
                String tretja_beseda = dobi_besedo_v_vrstici[2];

                Pattern ena = Pattern.compile("S[a-zA-z]{2}ei");
                    if(ena.matcher(tretja_beseda).matches()){
                    fw.write(prva_beseda+'\n');}
                Pattern dva = Pattern.compile("P[a-zA-z]{3}ei");
                    if(dva.matcher(tretja_beseda).matches()){
                        fw.write(prva_beseda+'\n'); 
                    }
                }


            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you didn't try using `println()`?

Comment: if you on windows replace '\n' with '\r\n'. Or just use good text editor (not notepad :) )

Comment: @shyam Because [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) does not declare `println()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a System line separator instead of using '\n'

```
            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            Pattern ena = Pattern.compile("S[a-zA-z]{2}ei");
                if(ena.matcher(tretja_beseda).matches()){
                fw.write(prva_beseda + newLine);}
            Pattern dva = Pattern.compile("P[a-zA-z]{3}ei");
                if(dva.matcher(tretja_beseda).matches()){
                    fw.write(prva_beseda + newLine); 
                }
```

Comment: Better use a text editor that is not limited to `\r\n` linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

Add fw.flush() at the end of your program.

Look at the flush method inherited from OutputStreamWriter [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).